# Data file location relative to html when running Azure Maps tutorials locally - atlas.io.read()

Tags: azure-maps

Trying to determine how to revise the atlas.ioread() function from the Azure Maps tutorial below to read the data locally on my windows machine.

```
   atlas.io.read(window.location.origin + '/Common/data/Gpx/Route66Attractions.xml')
```

Does the 'window.location.origins +' work with local files?

I have nested the .xml file similarly to the above string, relative to the html file, however, it does reading the file when the map is launched.

Azure Maps Tutorial:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Spatial%20IO%20Module/Load%20spatial%20data%20(simple).html

Answer (score 0):

That function won't be able to access local files directly as the URL must be a http or https URL. There are a couple of approaches you can take.

If you plan to host the file later, you can host it locally on localhost and then have a URL pointing to it.

If you want to access local files, you will first need to load the file into your app using the file input tag and the FileReader class. Once you have the raw file data (text), you can pass that into the atlas.io.read function and it will process if for you. Here is a simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>   
<head> 
    <title>Read Text File</title> 
    
    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add reference to the Azure Maps Spatial IO module. -->
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/spatial/0/atlas-spatial.min.js"></script>
</head>   
<body> 
    <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile"> 
      
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function() {
        var input = document.getElementById('inputfile');
        
        input.addEventListener('change', function() { 
        
            var fr = new FileReader(); 
            fr.onload = function(){ 
                atlas.io.read(fr.result).then(function(r){
                    //r is the parsed data. Do something with it.
                });
            } 
              
            fr.readAsText(input.files[0]); 
        });
    });
    </script> 
</body>   
</html>
```